# mongo-go-driver aggregate call always returns error

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I'm trying to do an aggregation with mongo-go-driver (MongoDB team driver for Golang) and I can't see what I'm doing wrong here:

```
// group
group, e := bson.ParseExtJSONObject(`
    {
      "$group": {
        "_id":{
          "ProductCode":"$ProductCode",
          "Dir":"$Dir",
          "WharehouseID":"$WharehouseID"
        }
      }
    }
`)


cursor, e := myCollection.Aggregate(
    context.Background(),
    group,
)

// e output: "(Location40324) Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '_id'"
```

This is a mongodb error but if I execute this query in a mongodb native client I get the results and no error occurs.

Comment: Can you show your working mongo direct query?

Comment: db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate(
    [  
      {  
        "$group":{  
          "_id":{  
            "ProductCode":"$ProductCode",
            "Dir":"$Dir",
            "WharehouseID":"$WharehouseID"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to parsing a string of [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) to build an aggregation pipeline, you could also construct a [bson.Array](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson#Array) object (typed):

For example:

```
pipeline := bson.NewArray(
    bson.VC.DocumentFromElements(
        bson.EC.SubDocumentFromElements(
            "$group",
            bson.EC.SubDocumentFromElements(
                "_id",
                bson.EC.String("ProductCode","$ProductCode"),
                bson.EC.String("Dir","$Dir"),
                bson.EC.String("WharehouseID","$WharehouseID"),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
cursor, err := collection.Aggregate(context.Background(), pipeline)
```

The above snippet is compatible with the current [mongo-go-driver version 0.0.12](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/releases/tag/v0.0.12)

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

Two mistakes I was making:

1 - I have to parse an array of JSON objects

2 - No new lines before closing "`"

Here is the working example:

```
    group, e := bson.ParseExtJSONArray(`[{
      "$group": {
        "_id":{
          "ProductCode":"$ProductCode",
          "Dir":"$Dir",
          "WharehouseID":"$WharehouseID"
        }
      }
    }]`)

    cursor, e := myCollection.Aggregate(
       context.Background(),
       group,
    )
```